# Is there a place to download Maps API style themes?

Tags: google-maps

I know there's a map style wizard, but that starts from the default map style. I see a lot of style maps online that are pretty similar to one another, and I would like to start from an already-styled map and tweak it from there. Is there a gallery of different styled maps somewhere, where I can copy the style to my map?